# PEM encoded certificate error when trying to import new Composer card

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am having some problems setting my network up in Composer. It is a single organisation and i have been following and adapting the multi-org tutorial [https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org](http://Multi%20org%20tutorial) to try and get TLS working.

When i try and import the card i get the following error:

Error: Failed to create client from connection profile. Error: PEM encoded certificate is required.
Command failed

I have checked the TLS certs in my connection.json file:

```html
{
    "name": "my-network",
    "x-type": "hlfv1",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "Org1",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300",
                    "eventHub": "300",
                    "eventReg": "300"
                },
                "orderer": "300"
            }
        }
    },
    "channels": {
        "mychannel": {
            "orderers": [
                "orderer.my-network"
            ],
            "peers": {
                "peer0.org1.my-network": {
                    "endorsingPeer": true,
                    "chaincodeQuery": true,
                    "eventSource": true
                },
                "peer1.org1.my-network": {
                    "endorsingPeer": true,
                    "chaincodeQuery": true,
                    "eventSource": true
                },
              "peer2.org1.my-network": {
                    "endorsingPeer": true,
                    "chaincodeQuery": true,
                    "eventSource": true
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Org1": {
            "mspid": "Org1MSP",
            "peers": [
                "peer0.org1.my-network",
                "peer1.org1.my-network",
                "peer2.org1.my-network"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.org1.my-network"
            ]
        }
    },
    "orderers": {
        "orderer.my-network": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:7050",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "orderer.my-network"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\noCM1L8lHYAIgI0Oq5VO6ucOMMw5e9CDsiCYU40sMAlgAJEYX/5AaZ1M=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            }
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.my-network": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:7051",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.my-network"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIICSDCCAe+gAwIBAgIQUzZZpkSRmpv6cj8Bta1BezAKBggqhkjOPQQDAjB2MQsw\nCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBxMNU2FuIEZy\nYW5jaXNjbzEZMBcGA1UEChMQb3JnMS5sb2ctbmV0d29yazEfMB0GA1UEAxMWdGxz\nY2Eub3JnMS5sb2ctbmV0d29yazAeFw0xODEyMDIxNzUwMDZaFw0yODExMjkxNzUw\nMDZaMHYxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYwFAYDVQQH\nEw1TYW4gRnJhbmNpc2NvMRkwFwYDVQQKExBvcmcxLmxvZy1uZXR3b3JrMR8wHQYD\nVQQDExZ0bHNjYS5vcmcxLmxvZy1uZXR3b3JrMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0D\nAQcDQgAEIdyjFaWd9I3kU+Kdh9z+vJttthzyFLPgcoXBWAT18zX7r7fRLxcBMF9d\nQazzpz2A55YG5rCm5NAeV3ugkHy5AaNfMF0wDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgGmMA8GA1Ud\nJQQIMAYGBFUdJQAwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zApBgNVHQ4EIgQgYtzVJNNdNjo+\n4FVhytdhGQr1fT6PbXfV0mKt3AU2g48wCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIDRwAwRAIgH7ADGx8D\nZsyTbeZ12S+1tMRmGo1tx6xpPzUGYx7hcGcCICDps+r+lvHeTaKVpENDPJaj5hcd\nOXkvHWYb2/sMguGc\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            }
        },
        "peer1.org1.my-network": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:8051",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.org1.my-network" 
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nOXkvHWYb2/sMguGc\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            }

        },
        "peer2.org1.my-network": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:9051",
            "gprcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer2.org1.my-network"
            },
            "tlsCerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nOXkvHWYb2/sMguGc\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            }
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.org1.my-network": {
            "url": "http://localhost:7054",
            "caName": "ca_peerOrg1",
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have not included couchdb yet, the docker-compose-cli.yaml is below:

```html
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

networks:
  byfn:

services:

  ca.org1.my-network:
    container_name: ca_peerOrg1
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.my-network-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/cc074f628fe7cb97e8147a8824fa564ddced245c324be7fb7660ee6fccf9cea2_sk
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.my-network-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/cc074f628fe7cb97e8147a8824fa564ddced245c324be7fb7660ee6fccf9cea2_sk -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.my-network/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    networks:
      - byfn

  # Should be either 3, 5 or 7 zookeepers to avoid split-brain scenarios, and larger than 1 to avoid a single point of failure
  zookeeper0:
    container_name: zookeeper0
    image: hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper
    environment:
         - ZOO_MY_ID=1
         - ZOO_SERVERS=server.1=zookeeper0:2888:3888 server.2=zookeeper1:2888:3888 server.3=zookeeper2:2888:3888
    ports:
         - 2181
         - 2888
         - 3888
    networks:
         - byfn

  zookeeper1:
    container_name: zookeeper1
    image: hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper
    environment:
         - ZOO_MY_ID=2
         - ZOO_SERVERS=server.1=zookeeper0:2888:3888 server.2=zookeeper1:2888:3888 server.3=zookeeper2:2888:3888
    ports:
         - 2181
         - 2888
         - 3888
    networks:
         - byfn

  zookeeper2:
    container_name: zookeeper2
    image: hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper
    environment:
         - ZOO_MY_ID=3
         - ZOO_SERVERS=server.1=zookeeper0:2888:3888 server.2=zookeeper1:2888:3888 server.3=zookeeper2:2888:3888
    command: /bin/bash -c 'sleep 6000000000000000000'
    ports:
         - 2181
         - 2888
         - 3888
    networks:
         - byfn

  # Should be at least 4 nodes in the kafka cluster for crash tollerance
  kafka0:
        image: hyperledger/fabric-kafka
        container_name: kafka0
        environment:
            - KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_MS=-1
            - KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES=103809024
            - KAFKA_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES=103809024
            - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=0
            - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
            - KAFKA_UNCLEAN_LEADER_ELECTION_ENABLE=false
            - KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR=3
            - KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS=2
            - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper0:2181,zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181
        ports:
            - 9092
        depends_on:
            - zookeeper0
            - zookeeper1
            - zookeeper2
        links:
            - zookeeper0:zookeeper0
            - zookeeper1:zookeeper1
            - zookeeper2:zookeeper2
        networks:
            - byfn

  kafka1:
        image: hyperledger/fabric-kafka
        container_name: kafka1
        environment:
            - KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_MS=-1
            - KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES=103809024
            - KAFKA_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES=103809024
            - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
            - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
            - KAFKA_UNCLEAN_LEADER_ELECTION_ENABLE=false
            - KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR=3
            - KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS=2
            - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper0:2181,zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181
        ports:
            - 9092
        depends_on:
            - zookeeper0
            - zookeeper1
            - zookeeper2
        links:
            - zookeeper0:zookeeper0
            - zookeeper1:zookeeper1
            - zookeeper2:zookeeper2
        networks:
            - byfn

  kafka2:
        image: hyperledger/fabric-kafka
        container_name: kafka2
        environment:
            - KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_MS=-1
            - KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES=103809024
            - KAFKA_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES=103809024
            - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=2
            - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
            - KAFKA_UNCLEAN_LEADER_ELECTION_ENABLE=false
            - KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR=3
            - KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS=2
            - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper0:2181,zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181
        ports:
            - 9092
        depends_on:
            - zookeeper0
            - zookeeper1
            - zookeeper2
        links:
            - zookeeper0:zookeeper0
            - zookeeper1:zookeeper1
            - zookeeper2:zookeeper2
        networks:
            - byfn

  kafka3:
        image: hyperledger/fabric-kafka
        container_name: kafka3
        environment:
            - KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_MS=-1
            - KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES=103809024
            - KAFKA_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES=103809024
            - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=3
            - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
            - KAFKA_UNCLEAN_LEADER_ELECTION_ENABLE=false
            - KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR=3
            - KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS=2
            - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper0:2181,zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181
        ports:
            - 9092
        depends_on:
            - zookeeper0
            - zookeeper1
            - zookeeper2
        links:
            - zookeeper0:zookeeper0
            - zookeeper1:zookeeper1
            - zookeeper2:zookeeper2
        networks:
            - byfn

  orderer.my-network:
    extends:
      file:   base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: orderer.my-network
    container_name: orderer.my-network
    depends_on:
            - kafka0
            - kafka1
            - kafka2
            - kafka3
    links:
            - kafka0:kafka0
            - kafka1:kafka1
            - kafka2:kafka2
            - kafka3:kafka3
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.org1.my-network:
    container_name: peer0.org1.my-network
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.org1.my-network
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.org1.my-network:
    container_name: peer1.org1.my-network
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer1.org1.my-network
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer2.org1.my-network:
    container_name: peer2.org1.my-network
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer2.org1.my-network
    networks:
      - byfn

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
    tty: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.my-network:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.my-network/peers/peer0.org1.my-network/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.my-network/peers/peer0.org1.my-network/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.my-network/peers/peer0.org1.my-network/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.my-network/users/Admin@org1.my-network/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    # command: /bin/bash -c './scripts/script.sh ${CHANNEL_NAME} ${DELAY} ${LANG}; sleep $TIMEOUT'
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    depends_on:
      - orderer.my-network
      - peer0.org1.my-network
      - peer1.org1.my-network
      - peer2.org1.my-network
    networks:
      - byfn
```

I am not using the byfn.sh to start the network, but manually with:

docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up -d

I have not loaded any sample chaincode. I have joined the orderer and three peers to the channel in the CLI.

Is there something i am missing with the certificate authority when starting the network?

Bit stuck at getting this going so any help would be very much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `peer2.org1.my-network` definition has a mistake in it, you specified `tlsCerts` when it should be `tlsCACerts`.

Comment: Many thanks! I can now create the card. However network install is now failing. Error 14 unavailable: Connect Failed. In one of the peer logs there is also the following error: ERRO 3b2 [][7f6b6126] simulateProposal() resulted in chaincode name:"lscc"  response status 500 for txid:. Seems to be a problem with chaincode but i have not loaded any appart from the business archive, is it necessary to install the sample chaincode? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: The problem you are seeing is possibly because the identity you are using to try to install chaincode onto a peer, is not authorised to do so.With the Composer development server setup, it creates an identity for you called 'PeerAdmin' which it uses to deploy business networks (ie has the authority). But as you're using your own custom fabric then you need to look into how to import crypto material for a peer administrator into your composer wallet using the 'composer identity import' command documented here https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/reference/composer.card.import ..

Comment: (the link provided is also to '0.19' ....but bear in mind there are later versions of Composer/matching Fabric levels - see the release notes https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/releases - also see this announcement https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/composer/message/125

Comment: Thanks Paul. I am using the command: composer card import --file PeerAdmin@my-network.card --card PeerAdmin@my-network. Which is telling me that the card has been successfully imported. I am starting fabric 1.1 and composer version is 0.19.

Comment: I can see in the connection.json file that has been created in ~/.composer/cards/PeerAdmin@my-network/connection.json the following settings: "x-type":"hlfv1","version":"1.0.0". I must be doing something wrong in the configuration. I was trying to use version 1.1 as it is compatible with the tool Caliper which i wanted to try out when things are up and running. Any ideas how i may remedy my compatability issues?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue:

> ✖ Installing business network. This may take a minute...
>
> Error: PEM encoded certificate is required. Command failed

And, In my case ***tlsCACerts*** pem certificate was missing

```
"tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": ""
              }
```

I extracted the certificate using the following command:

```
awk 'NF {sub(/\r/, ""); printf "%s\\n",$0;}' ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/ca.crt > ca-orderer.txt
```

And pasted the content of ca-orderer.txt file in the above tlsCACerts pem attribute.